# R data.frame character column doesn't behave as expected

Tags: r

I'm having a problem with a data.frame.  To make it very simple I start with

```
    test<-data.frame(char=character(10), numr=numeric(10))
    test$char[1]<-"ery"
```

The result is

```
    Warning message:In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, 1, value = c(NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  :
   invalid factor level, NAs generated
```

If I do `mode(test$char)` I get `[1] "numeric"`

If I do `mode(test$numr)` I get `[1] "character"`

I can also do `test$numr[1]<-"fjfj"` without an error and the data is stored in that particular place.

If I instead of setting the data.frame with `character(10)` I just do everything as numeric then as in the previous example it will allow me to change the numeric to character simply by storing a string to something in a column even though it was previously defined as numeric.
Why does R treat character differently than I expect as in my example?

Comment: See the part about `stringsAsFactors` in `?data.frame`

Comment: or you can modify `test$char[1]<-"ery"` with `test$char[1]<-as.character("ery")`

Comment: by the way, if you get acceptable answers to your questions on SO you should consider clicking on the checkmark to accept them ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a little suspicious of your results posted above.

```
>     test<-data.frame(char=character(10), numr=numeric(10))
> str(test)
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ char: Factor w/ 1 level "": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 $ numr: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
> mode(test$char)
[1] "numeric"
> mode(test$numr)
[1] "numeric"
```

This is telling me that `char` is a factor, `numr` is numeric, and both are stored as numeric (factors have an additional attribute that maps the numeric level codes to labels).  You're getting an error because you're trying to set a value in `char` that isn't included in the list of levels (which includes only the blank string `""`).  As @GSee says in the comments, you probably wanted `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`:

```
> test<-data.frame(char=character(10), numr=numeric(10), 
                   stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
> str(test)
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ char: chr  "" "" "" "" ...
 $ numr: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
> test$char[1] <- "ery" ## no error
```

You can set `options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` to make this your global default behaviour.  There is a tradeoff here between convenience for yourself and confusion the next time you forget that you have this option set globally, ask a question on StackOverflow, and have everyone wonder why you're getting different answers ...

Finally, as you mentioned above, if `char` starts out as numeric, R will silently coerce it to a character string when you try to set an element to a character value.  I think this is actually pretty bad design, but it's too deeply built into R's behaviour to change now ...

```
> test<-data.frame(char=numeric(10), numr=numeric(10))
> test$char[1] <- "ery"
> str(test)
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ char: chr  "ery" "0" "0" "0" ...
 $ numr: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: yeah that stringsAsFactors option was perfect.  Mid-way through typing this up when I realized that the columns I set as numeric could then store strings I just decide to create the initial data frame with all columns called numeric and then just stick strings in there since that worked.

Comment: it does work, but in the long run you will probably be better off deciding how you want your data structured and trying to enforce it/make things consistent, rather than allowing R to coerce things willy-nilly (partly for reasons of efficiency and partly for clarity)